# How does grails pass arguments to controller methods?

Tags: grails

In grails controller examples, I have seen save(Model modelInstance) and save(). I tried them both, both of them works. I imagine grails instantiates the modelInstance with the params. Is my assumption correct?

I also noticed in index(Integer max), does the param has to be named max? or any name would work as long as it is a number?

How does these passing of arguments work underneath?

Comment: Have you read the documentation before posting? It's an obvious starting point - http://grails.org/doc/2.1.2/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding

Comment: Yes, I have scanned them before. Im just wondering if the same data binding process applies in method parameters.

Comment: Controller can't read your thoughts :) the name should be same. also accessible by params.paramName

Comment: Sure, it's well described in chapter called "Data Binding and Action Arguments" in the link above. BTW it's better for understanding to stick with an official terminology and use "action" instead of "controller method" - it's also not the same thing because controller method does not necesserily mean action.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you write a controller like this...

```
class MyController {
    def actionOne() {
        // your code here
    }

    def actionTwo(int max) {
        // your code here
    }

    def actionThree(SomeCommandObject co) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

The Grails compiler will turn that in to something like this (not exactly this, but this describes effectively what is happening in a way that I think addresses your question)...

```
class MyController {
    def actionOne() {
        // Grails adds some code here to
        // do some stuff that the framework needs

        // your code here
    }

    // Grails generates this method...
    def actionTwo() {
        // the parameter doesn't have to be called
        // "max", it could be anything.
        int max = params.int('max')
        actionTwo(max)
    }

    def actionTwo(int max) {
        // Grails adds some code here to
        // do some stuff that the framework needs

        // your code here
    }

    // Grails generates this method...
    def actionThree() {
        def co = new SomeCommandObject()
        bindData co, params
        co.validate()
        actionThree(co)
    }

    def actionThree(SomeCommandObject co) {
        // Grails adds some code here to
        // do some stuff that the framework needs

        // your code here
    }
}
```

There is other stuff going on to do things like impose allowedMethods checks, impose error handling, etc.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks :)