# Grails rest-api app to handle multiple params

Tags: rest, grails

Using Grails 3.1.3, I created a rest-api so that I am able to capture GET requests that not only query for one parameter, but multiple if needed. I don't know how to code this correctly inside the UrlMappings file. Here are the details.

Domain class:

```
class ProdDetail {
  Integer pid
  String title
  String category
  Integer year
}
```

And some of these inside the BootStrap:

```
new ProdDetail(pid:'101', title:'No Highway', author:'Nevil Shute', category:'fiction', year:1948).save(failOnError:true)
new ProdDetail(pid:'214', title:'In the Country of Men', author:'Hisham Matar', category:'misery', year:2007).save(failOnError:true)
```

Controller:

```
protected List<ProdDetail> listAllResources(Map params) {

  println params

  try {
     ProdDetail.where {
        if (params.category && params.maxYear) {
           category == params.category && year <= params.int('maxYear')
        } else if (params.category) {
           category == params.category
        } else if (params.maxYear) {
           year <= params.int('maxYear')
        } else {
           pid > 0
        }
     }.list()
  } catch (Exception e) {
     []
  }
}
```

UrlMappings:

```
static mappings = {
   "/prodDetails"(resources:'prodDetail')
   "/prodDetails/category/$category?"(controller:'prodDetail', action:'index')
   "/prodDetails/yearUnder/$maxYear?"(controller:'prodDetail', action:'index')
   // the line below is not right I think, what's the correct format?
   "/prodDetails/combo/$category?&$maxYear?"(controller:'prodDetail', action:'index')
}
```

Now, where as these two curls would work:

```
curl localhost:8080/prodDetails/category/misery
curl localhost:8080/prodDetails/yearUnder/2007
```

This one fails to go into the desired clause in the controller to detect both params:

```
curl localhost:8080/prodDetails/combo/?category=misery&maxYear=2007
```

It just detects 'category' but not the 'maxYear' which it considers as 'null'.

How can I cater for such a `curl` please?

Comment: If you sent the UrlMappings to: `"/prodDetails/combo/$category"(controller:'prodDetail', action:'index')` and then curl `localhost:8080/prodDetails/combo/misery?maxYear=2007` what is the contents of the params map?

Comment: Just tried it. It returns both records (which it shouldn't). The output from the controller for `println params` is `[controller:prodDetail, action:index, category:misery, max:10]`

Comment: Wait, sorry, your suggestion worked! It worked with I removed the `-i` in the curl command. Got to know why... I will write some more but wanted to thank you for now.

Comment: Yep, I had the mistake of leaving -i in the curl command without the proper headers to apply your suggestion (edited and fixed). So, your suggestion works. But let me take this a step further. What If I wanted to make a query on three or more params, this approach wouldn't work, right? Say I wanted to query on category, maxYear and name for example, what would the entry in the UrlMappings look like then? The curl command would be something like `curl localhost:8080/prodDetails/combo/misery?maxYear=2010&title=common`.

Comment: Here, `println params' didn't see 'title', and swapping the & for ? gave this: `[maxYear:2010?title=common, controller:prodDetail, action:index, category:misery, max:10]`.

Comment: You should be able to add as many parameters as you want, the `curl localhost:8080/prodDetails/combo/misery?maxYear=2010&title=common` should work as long as you have the correct UrlMapping, the UrlMapping should have only `"/prodDetails/combo/$category"(controller:'prodDetail', action:'index')` with no question mark after `$category`

Comment: This one didn't work. The params caught here are `[maxYear:2010, controller:prodDetail, action:index, category:misery, max:10]`.

Comment: @photon: I am really sorry, your second suggestion works like charms (actually, the last response I replied says it - I got both params shown, maxYear and category). If it's any consolation, I didn't go to work today because of a nasty cold, and it shows :-) Thanks for your help. I wish you could post your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to specify the parameters in UrlMappings if those params are not part of the URL:

No need of this:

```
"/prodDetails/combo/$category&?$maxYear?"(controller:'prodDetail', action:'index')
```

Yes you need this to match the URL to a controller/action (but remove the ?)

```
"/prodDetails/yearUnder/$maxYear?"(controller:'prodDetail', action:'index')
```

Also, you don't need Map params in `listAllResources(Map params)`

"params" is an injected property of controllers, the println params will work OK with: `listAllResources()`

What I would do is to define:

`listAllResources(String category, int maxYear, ...)` where ... are all the params that action can receive, most would be optional, so you will receive a null value if not included in your request.

Remember: UrlMappings are to map URLs to controller/actions, and you have the same controller/action, so I would remove all the mappings and process the optional parameters in the action just checking which are null or not.

**Edit (considering comments)**

*Q: the method is not overloaded to handle params like that*

A: methods are dynamic, this is Grails / Groovy, not Java. It will call the action method even if all the params are null. I would recommend you to go through the Grails controller documentation in detail.

*Q:  found that the listAllResources method was never called*

A: remove the protected keyword from the action, only subclasses would be able to invoke that method. Also, you can add an UrlMapping to avoid users to invoke that URL (match the URL and return 404 Not Available or something like that)

*Q: I want to handle a GET request like this localhost:8080/prodDetails/combo?category=misery&year=2016&title=commonTitle, how exactly should the i) entry in UrlMappings, and ii) the listAllResources method look like?*

A:

```
static mappings = {
   // if "compo" comes in the action portion, map that to the listAllResources method
   // as I said, if all parameters comes in the query string, no further actions are needed, if you need parameters to be part of the URL path, then you need to play with the $xxxx in the URL
   "/prodDetails/combo"(controller:'prodDetail', action:'listAllResources')
}

def listAllResources()
{
   println params
   // logic here
   render "OK"
}
```

Check:

- https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/params.html
- https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html
- [How does grails pass arguments to controller methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23511688/how-does-grails-pass-arguments-to-controller-methods)

Comment: The way you are using [listAllResources](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.1.3/api/grails/rest/RestfulController.html#listAllResources(java.util.Map)) won't work I think - the method is not overloaded to handle params like that.

Comment: I haven't tried it but I'm pretty sure I've seen controller methods used like that as well.  It could work, though I personally don't like methods that accept lots of parameters.

Comment: @mohsenmadi I'm building apps with Grails since v0.4.3. Yes that *works* with the newest versions, check http://mrhaki.blogspot.com.uy/2012/02/grails-goodness-binding-method.html

Comment: @photon you can always define a no param method for the action and access all parameters through the injected params variable, this was stated on my answer.

Comment: I have tried it before answring @PabloPazos, and found that the `listAllResources` method was never called (the `println` statement was never executed), which lead me to think that the overloading was not accepted per se here. I will take a look at your reference and say more as I find out. Many thanks.

Comment: So just to be clear, if I want to handle a GET request like this `localhost:8080/prodDetails/combo?category=misery&year=2016&title=commonTitle`, how exactly should the i) entry in UrlMappings, and ii) the listAllResources method look like? You could also help suggest a better URL path instead of the one I am using.

Comment: I like your link it gives a very good idea how to map url params to method arguments. But, it's a custom method though, not using the listAllRrsources one (not that I care about that now).

Comment: @PabloPazos Precisely what I was looking for! Thank you for your elaboration. I will tell how it goes as I get to coding it, but it's logical and clear.

Comment: @mohsenmadi no problem, please test it in a clean project to see if it works OK, so you know if it doesn't work, is not a problem in another component of your app.

Comment: Tried it but didn't quite work. With the request `curl localhost:8080/prodDetails/combo?category=misery&year=2015` and all else as you suggested in the `UrlMappings` and the controller method, only the first param is detected (`println params` gives `[category:misery, controller:prodDetail, action:listAllResources]`). I am calling it correctly, right?

Comment: You have the app name prodDetails and in my example that is the controller

Comment: Hey @PabloPazos, sorry I didn't realize you responded back. This link shows a [prodDetails](https://github.com/mohsenmadi/ols) app - feel free to experiment and apply your suggestion, I hope you could get it running.

Answer (score 2):

It kind of depends on what you want your URLs to look like, but assuming you want your requests to look like this:

`http://localhost:8080/prodDetails/combo/misery?maxYear=2007&title=common`

The UrlMappings should look like

```
static mappings = {
   "/prodDetails/combo/$category"(controller:'prodDetail', action:'index')
}
```

Then the `params` object in the controller should have both whatever's in the place of `$category`, in this example misery, and the other parameters after the `?` as well.

If you want the parameters to be in the path you can do this:

```
static mappings = {
   "/prodDetails/combo/$category/$title/$maxYear"(controller:'prodDetail', action:'index')
}
```

And the request would then be:

```
http://localhost:8080/prodDetails/combo/misery/common/2007
```

One other option would be to use a command object.  So if you had:

```
static mappings = {
   "/prodDetails/combosearch"(controller:'prodDetail', action:'comboSearch')
}
```

And then created an object beside the controller called ComboSearchCommand.groovy that looked like:

```
import grails.validation.Validateable
class ComboSearchCommand implements Validetable {
    String category
    String title
    int maxYear

    static constraints = {
        category blank: false, nullable: true
        title blank: false, nullable: true
        maxYear blank: false, nullable: true
    }
}
```

(Which you can do validation on just like a domain object)

And then in your controller you have the method take the command object instead of params

```
protected List<ProdDetail> comboSearch(ComboSearchCommand command) {
    println command.category
}
```

Then your URL would be

```
http://localhost:8080/prodDetails/combosearch?category=misery&maxYear=2007&title=common
```

And the parameters will bind to the command object.

I've used that quite a bit, you can share validations or have your command object inherit validations from domain objects, lots of flexibility.

https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#commandObjects

Comment: Thanks! The last solution is particularly what I was looking for also. I will give it a run tonight.